# "Vertical accordian" design with HTML5/CSS3?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an idea for my personal website layout. I'd like stacked menu items on the left side (with like 10% width) and content on the right side. By 'vertical abacus' (the original calculator with beads on a rod), I'd like menu items to appear as boxes of varying colors with a set height for each box. Because they're a set height, there will be a large portion of empty space (colored depending on what menu you select).

Utilizing the new HTML5/CSS3, I'd like to know how I'd go about creating the menu so that when you select an item, that particular item (and the items above it) slide up and stack to the top, while changing the color of the empty space below it according to the color of the respective menu item. When a menu item that is stacked at the top is selected, the items stacked below it will move back down to their original position.

First visit to the website:
[image: http://imgur.com/mLStvJL]

After clicking 'Page2':
[image: http://imgur.com/aD9b2hj]

(I'm such an excellent MSPaint artist, I know.)

Did I lose anyone yet? :)

Would I have to tweak this process with Javascript?

I'm not asking someone to code it for me (though obviously welcome), I just have no idea where to start since W3Schools.com is frowned upon and I have an amateur knowledge of the new features in HTML5/CSS3. Would something as seemingly simple as this be difficult to begin with?

Any help is greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: It's not exactly the same as what you describe, but if I understand your requirements correctly, the navigation element they call an accordion should be quite close?  A couple of implementations can be found here http://designscrazed.net/html5-css3-accordion-tabs/

Comment: I would use flex box layout for this one, however it is not very much backward compatible.

Comment: fvu: Thanks for the link. Interesting concepts in there. I think calling it an 'accordion' design is better suited for what I'd like.

Akxe: Ooh, I found this looking for flexbox layouts. I'm going with this as a last resort if I can't separate the menu items from the content. Thanks for the keyword. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes#Holy_Grail_Layout_example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Create a Fiddle for you:**

http://jsfiddle.net/M8bQH/

Please adapt Width/Height and colors to your needs!

***HTML:***

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="sideBar">
        <ul id="myMenu">
            <li class="topic1 activeItem">Home</li>
            <li class="topic2">Page 2</li>
            <li class="topic3">Page 3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="mainContent activeContent">
        Content1
    </div>
    <div class="mainContent">
        Content2
    </div>
    <div class="mainContent">
        Content3
    </div>
</div>
```

***JavaScript (jQuery needed!)***

```
$('#myMenu li').click(function(){
    // Set active menu item
    $('#myMenu li').removeClass('activeItem');
    $(this).addClass('activeItem');

    // Set active content according to item
    $('.mainContent').removeClass('activeContent');
    $('.mainContent').eq($(this).index()).addClass('activeContent');

    // Adapt background color of content according to item
    $('.mainContent.activeContent').css('background-color', $(this).css('background-color'));
});
```

***CSS:***

```
#container {
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
}

#myMenu {
    list-style-type:none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#myMenu li {
    width: 100px;
    height:48px;
    border-bottom: 5px solid black;
    -webkit-transition: height linear 0.5s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: height linear 0.5s;
}
#myMenu li:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0px;
}
#sideBar {
    width: 100px;
    height: 600px;
    float:left;
    border-right: 5px solid black;
}

.mainContent {
    width: 700px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: gray;
    display: none;
}

.topic1 {
    background-color: gray;
}
.topic2 {
    background-color: #33CCFF;
}
.topic3 {
    background-color: #99FF00;
}

.activeItem {
    height: 494px !important;
}

.activeContent {
    display: block !important;
}
```